# Collect video from camera and display it in a navigator

Tags: camera, pi-3b+, streaming-video, gstreamer

I'm trying to collect live video stream from a camera. The camera output is analogic so I'm using an Analogic to USB converter connected to my Raspberry.
I'm looking for a good solution to collect the video and stream it on a website. I have already tried to achieve my goal using Motion, but Motion is using 100% of my processor when it is running. And on the website the stream has a latency of almost 4 seconds.

That's why I'm trying to use an alternative. I have heard about Gstreamer but I can't figure out how to make it works. I'm always having errors about interlacing options or something else.

To launch Gstreamer I use this command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 !
```

The command is followed by diffent pipes separated by "!". I have tried multiples combinations.

Do you know how to use Gstreamer or do you know where I could find a good tutorial? I have spend hours looking for a good one but I didn't find any.

Or do you have an idea of another I could use to achieve my goal?

UPDATE: I found this command to display the video from my webcam on Raspbian Desktop.

```
gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! autovideosink
```

Now my problem is to stream my video through my network.
With the following command it seemed to have worked but I couldn't access video with my navigator.

```
gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! udpsink host=XXX.XXX.XX.XX port=8081
```

I had the following message as a warning:

> UDP package is too long

By the way the quality of the collected video is a bit low. When I display the real image on a screen it looks perfect. So maybe I'm not using all the right plugins from Gstreamer to obtain a correct result.

Comment: Check out [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3747/106927). I don't think you want to use `!` at all, unless you understand what it does.

Comment: I need to use them because gst-launch-1.0 commands work with it.